# Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment' after running ng e2e command

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables, e2e-testing

I'm new to Angular and Typescript and I'm trying to perform e2e testing on my Angular project by running the "ng e2e" command but I keep receiving the following error:

```
E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment'
```

I've taken a look at related posts here on SO, but none of the solutions have worked for this situation or they have no answer. I've tried changing the relative path of the import to "../environments/environment" and "../../environments/environment" but the path doesn't resolve.

I've tried moving the environments folder into the e2e/src directory as well but no success.

Is this related to the fact that there are 2 src folders?

Any and all suggestions all welcome.

The error points to my app.e2e-spec.ts file as seen in the screenshot below (blurred partial path for privacy):

[image: Command line after running ng e2e]

In my app.e2e-spec.ts file, my environment import resolves properly:

[image: app.e2e-spec.ts imports]

My project structure seems pretty straightforward:

[image: Project structure]

Comment: change it to `../../src/environments/environment`

Comment: @EmptyBrain Yupp, that was it. I thought I tried that already and that the problem was deeper than that. Sigh, I feel silly. Thank you, friend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was just using the wrong path, thanks to @EmptyBrain for pointing that out.

So my import path should have been:

```
./../src/environments/environment
```